# How do I convert an arbitrary double to an integer while avoiding undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Let's say I've got a function that accepts a 64-bit integer, and I want to call
it with a `double` with arbitrary numeric value (i.e. it may be very large in
magnitude, or even infinite):

```
void DoSomething(int64_t x);

double d = [...];
DoSomething(d);
```

Paragraph 1 of [conv.fpint] in the C++11 standard says this:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion trun- cates; that is, the fractional part
>   is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
>   be represented in the destination type.

Therefore there are many values of `d` above that will cause undefined
behavior. I would like conversion to saturate, so that values greater than
`std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()` (called `kint64max` below), including
infinity, become that value, and similarly with the minimum representable
value. This seems the natural approach:

```
double clamped = std::min(d, static_cast<double>(kint64max));
clamped = std::max(clamped, static_cast<double>(kint64min));
DoSomething(clamped);
```

But, the next paragraph in the standard says this:

> A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of a floating point type. The result is exact
>   if possible. If the value being converted is in the range of values
>   that can be represented but the value cannot be represented exactly,
>   it is an implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or
>   higher representable value.

So `clamped` may still wind up being `kint64max + 1`, and behavior may still be
undefined.

What is the simplest portable way to do what I'm looking for? Bonus points if
it also gracefully handles `NaN`s.

**Update**: To be more precise, I would like the following to all be true of an
`int64_t SafeCast(double)` function that solves this problem:

1. For any double `d`, calling `SafeCast(d)` does not perform undefined behavior
   according to the standard, nor does it throw an exception or otherwise abort.
2. For any double `d` in the range `[-2^63, 2^63)`,
   `SafeCast(d) == static_cast<int64_t>(d)`. That is, `SafeCast` agrees with C++'s
   conversion rules wherever the latter is defined.
3. For any double `d >= 2^63`, `SafeCast(d) == kint64max`.
4. For any double `d < -2^63`, `SafeCast(d) == kint64min`.

I suspect the true difficulty here is in figuring out whether `d` is in the
range `[-2^63, 2^63)`. As discussed in the question and in comments to other
answers, I think using a cast of `kint64max` to `double` to test for the upper
bound is a non-starter due to undefined behavior. It may be more promising to
use `std::pow(2, 63)`, but I don't know whether this is guaranteed to be exactly
2^63.

Comment: `static_cast` `kint64max + 1ULL` (or `(uint64_t) 1`), which should be exactly representable, and then use `std::nextafter` to get the previous representable value, and clamp down to that.

Comment: What @T.C. said. The standard doesn't guarantee it, but integer powers of 2 can be stored without loss up to the limits of the floating point format, in every floating point system I'm aware of.

Comment: What about `NaN` and `Infinity`?

Comment: @ArnonZilca `min` and `max` will work for Infinity but not NaN. You need separate testing for that case, and it's unclear what should be returned.

Comment: What value would you want in the case of NaN?

Comment: @T.C.: I don't quite grok your comment. Could you expand it to a detailed answer?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Zero would be fine. Whatever is convenient.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's not about the value, but about knowing the cast failed to set the int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this is simpler to do than I thought. Thanks to Michael O'Reilly
for the basic idea of this solution.

The heart of the matter is figuring out whether the truncated double will be
representable as an `int64_t`. You can do this easily using [`std::frexp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

static constexpr int64_t kint64min = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
static constexpr int64_t kint64max = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();

int64_t SafeCast(double d) {
  // We must special-case NaN, for which the logic below doesn't work.
  if (std::isnan(d)) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Find that exponent exp such that
  //     d == x * 2^exp
  // for some x with abs(x) in [0.5, 1.0). Note that this implies that the
  // magnitude of d is strictly less than 2^exp.
  //
  // If d is infinite, the call to std::frexp is legal but the contents of exp
  // are unspecified.
  int exp;
  std::frexp(d, &exp);

  // If the magnitude of d is strictly less than 2^63, the truncated version
  // of d is guaranteed to be representable. The only representable integer
  // for which this is not the case is kint64min, but it is covered by the
  // logic below.
  if (std::isfinite(d) && exp <= 63) {
    return d;
  }

  // Handle infinities and finite numbers with magnitude >= 2^63.
  return std::signbit(d) ? kint64min : kint64max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't fit all the criteria, along with analysis for
why not. See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584177/1505451) for a better answer.

```
// Define constants from the question.
static constexpr int64_t kint64min = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min();
static constexpr int64_t kint64max = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();

int64_t SafeCast(double d) {
  // Handle NaN specially.
  if (std::isnan(d)) return 0;

  // Handle out of range below.
  if (d <= kint64min) return kint64min;

  // Handle out of range above.
  if (d >= kint64max) return kint64max;

  // At this point we know that d is in range.
  return d;
}
```

I believe this avoids undefined behavior. There is nothing to be wary of with
casting integers to doubles in the range checks. Assuming sanity in the way
that non-representable integers are converted (in particular that the mapping
is monotonic), by the time the range checks are past, we can be sure that `d`
is in `[-2^63, 2^63)`, as required for the implicit cast at the end of the
function.

I'm also confident that this clamps out of range values correctly.

The issue is criteria #2 from the update to my question. Consider an
implementation where `kint64max` is not representable as a double, but
`kint64max - 1` is. Further, assume that this is an implementation where
casting `kint64max` to a double yields the next lower representable value,
i.e. `kint64max - 1`. Let `d` be 2^63 - 2 (i.e. `kint64max - 1`). Then
`SafeCast(d)` is `kint64max`, because the range check converts `kint64max` to
a double, yielding a value equal to `d`. But `static_cast<int64_t>(d)` is
`kint64max - 1`.

Try as I might, I can't find a way to resolve this. Nor can I even write a
unit test that checks my criteria, without the unit test executing undefined
behavior. I feel like there is a deeper lesson to be learned here—something
about the impossibility of detecting whether an action in a system will cause
undefined behavior from inside the system itself, without causing undefined
behavior.

Comment: If an implementation uses anything resembling IEEE-754 math, INT64_MAX won't be precisely representable but INT64_MIN will be; would there be any problem with checking whether d >= 0 and -d>=INT64_MIN and, if so, casting -d to an int64_t and then inspecting the result?  That would avoid any need to extract an exponent.

Comment: INT64_MAX is required to be 0x7fffffffffffffff, and with IEEE-754 `double` the conversion result will round up by 1, to `0x1p63`.  (https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/).  A `static_assert( kint64max <= (int64_t)(double)kint64max );` may be sufficient for this check, or maybe `static_assert( kint64max <= (int64_t)(double)(kint64max - 1) );` to make sure even max-1 rounds up.  (Although that's not the case for 80-bit extended precision which can exactly represent every int64_t.)

Comment: Do you have a citation from a standard? I don't think 2^63-1 is guaranteed to round up; in fact I'm pretty sure I saw it round down while working on this problem. Anyway, please see the accepted answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without `std::frexp`. It exploits `uint64_t` for the tricky case.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

int64_t SafeCast(double d) {
    if (std::isnan(d)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (d < 0) {
        // Easy case to clamp, because std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() is
        // exactly representable as IEEE double.
        return static_cast<int64_t>(std::max<double>(d, std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()));
    }

    // Convert to uint64_t, clamping to range [0..2^63].
    uint64_t u = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::min<double>(d, static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 63));

    // Clamp to int64_t.
    return std::min(u, (static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 63) - 1U);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wonder if int64min is guaranteed to be representable by the standard? I know I'm talking about theoretical problems here, but just in a language lawyer sense.

Comment: @jacobsa - You are correct. If the target machine's `double`  has a severely limited exponent range (e.g. IEEE FP16), or a non-power-of-two base (e.g. base 10), then int64min might not be exactly representable. 

IBM has decimal floating-point on some of their machines as an option, but under a different type name. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-decimal-floating-point-built-in .

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
constexpr uint64_t weird_high_limit = (double)kint64max == (double)(kint64max-1);
int64_t clamped = (d >= weird_high_limit + kint64max)? kint64max: (d <= kint64min)? kint64min: int64_t(d);
```

I think this takes care of all the edge cases.  If `d < (double)kint64max`, then `(exact)d <= (exact)kint64max`.  Proof proceeds by contradiction of the fact that `(double)kint64max` is the next higher or lower representable value.

Comment: If `(double)kint64max` goes to the next lower representable value, and `d == (double)kint64max`, then you get `kint64max` even though you should get `int64_t(d)` (which is smaller than `kint64max`).

Comment: I think the standard allows for `kint64max - 1` to be exactly representable as a double, but `kint64max` to not be. Then `kint64max` may convert to the double `kint64max - 1` in the first comparison. So if `d` is `kint64max - 1`, it will incorrectly convert to `kint64max`.

Comment: @T.C.: Well, that isn't pretty, but it can be explicitly tested for.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I was just adding that unsigned long long.

Comment: @jacobsa: But then the error introduced is no more than 0.5ULP.  Can't see how that is a problem.  Tempted to revert back to the original, for that reason.

Comment: Well sure the error introduced is small, but of course it can be a problem if you assume a value is <= some other value, but it is not.

Answer (score -1):

`boost::numeric_cast`, that's how.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html

Comment: This was already an answer that was withdrawn. The source I found Googling [numeric_cast source] contains this expression for determining whether `arg` is in range: `!(arg > result_traits::max())`. I believe this may cause undefined behavior. `result_traits::max()` is allowed to become the double representing 2^63, then this will say that a value of 2^63 for `arg` is in range. But converting 2^63 to an `int64_t` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @jacobsa Ah, I don't have visibility to the withdrawn answer to see how that affected the flow of this discussion.

Comment: Yep, sorry, that's not really relevant. I guess what I'm saying is: it's good to know that `bost::numeric_cast` exists, but what I'm interested in here is what technique does it use. The source code I'm looking at does not look correct (or at least portable), but I may be looking at the wrong source code.

Comment: Perhaps there are some clues in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html. They mention an OverflowHandler policy, and a Float2IntRounder policy. How the rounding happens is shown in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/numeric_converter_policy_classes.html#boost_numericconversion.numeric_converter_policy_classes.policy_float2introunder. It is not immediately apparent if/where the documentation addresses the precision issues with range checking.