# How to convert int32t_t to int16_t(msb) and uint16_t(Lsb)? Without changing the original value

Tags: c++, bit, mask, bit-shift, shift

```
int32_t value32bit = somevalue;
int16_t high16 = value32bit >> 16;
uint16_t low16 = value32bit & 0xFFFF;
int32_t rebuild = (high16 << 16) | (low16 & 0xFFFF);
```

will this work even for negative value?

Comment: How are you going to fit 64 bits of double into 32 bits of int32_t without loss of data?

Comment: Is there something stopping you from putting a negative value into the double, then seeing if it works, and answering this question?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Just use the bit and imaginary bit components together as pairs :D

Comment: Fails if sizeof(int)==2

Comment: Possibly useful notes in https://stackoverflow.com/q/25857843/2864740 (a conversion from double can exceed both as int64_t and int32_t can exceed the bounds of the target type, which is where the "issue" is at static_cast call itself). After the static_cast the result "is" an integer *value* (fsvo, which has some finite range/size), so it might be worth removing the following code (or the static_cast code) depending on focus is: is it about the static_cast or about the bit manipulation after? (And yes, an int32 can definitely have negative values.. with a much smaller range than a double.)

Comment: In particular to the link above, see the quoted text: "*A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion trun- cates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.***" However, if the input double value is *within* the range of an int32 (which includes negative values), then it is guaranteed to result in a [truncated] value within the range. The rest of the linked question (and answer) goes on to discuss a 'safe' conversion and caveats.

Comment: `int32_t value32bit = static_cast<int32_t>(value);` is beyond senseless. If you want to stick to this, ask a question about 32-bit int to 16-bit ints. Otherwise, revise this idea. Consider double value 0.0000002352 (which would lose 4 digits of precision) and double value 1.2345x10^16 (which would lose 5 digits of precision). Oh, and scale would be loss too.

Comment: Think about this part: `low16 & 0xFFFF`. You take a 16-bit value and mask it so that only 16 bits remain? Hmm... What about this part: `high16 << 16`? You take your 16-bit value, shift it 16 bits, and the result is... what? (The latter will -- perhaps surprisingly -- work on some systems, but not all. The comment by doug is relevant.)

Comment: @user2864740 I'm just concerned about converting int32_t to int16_t and uint16_t? I don't know if the data will be preserved.

Comment: @Sunny95 Then remove the `double` part of the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

int32_t value32bit = static_cast<int32_t>(value);
This step is losing the precision.
you should make sure left shift to retain all the effective bits, i.e. decimal part.

Comment: int32_t value32bit = static_cast<int>(value < 0 ? value - 0.5 : value + 0.5); This will help round value.

Comment: That is just not enough to preserve the precision.