# Different behavior of double and int64_t conversion on new Apple silicon (arm64) vs. x86_64

Tags: c++, x86-64, arm64, floating-point-conversion

env: docker. gcc10 in arm64 debian. gcc7 in x86_64 debian.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
        double d = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();
        int64_t t = static_cast<int64_t>(d);
        printf("%lld\n", t);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

- arm64: 9223372036854775807
- x86_64: -9223372036854775808

Can someone help me understand why there is a difference?

Comment: your int64_t overflows.
Wild guess : `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()` can't be represented properly in double and rounds up to one integer, casting to `int64` then overflows. You should
print out what `d` contains.

Comment: Surely one remaining question is, why the behavior differs -- is it between CPUs or between GCC versions? only godbolt will tell.

Comment: Overflowing FP->int conversions on x86-64 produce the "integer indefinite" value, MSB set, all others clear.  ARM64 is different (perhaps saturating), or else you enabled optimization and constant-propagation removed the actual runtime conversion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25857843/1716339 -- here partially answered, as the result is implementation defined.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is the different behavior of the ARM architecture for overflows in the conversion (to int64_t in this case). It is documented here (for ARMv7): https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/d/Application-Level-Architecture/Application-Level-Programmers--Model/The-optional-Floating-point-extension/Floating-point-data-types-and-arithmetic?lang=en

TL:DR: The maximum representable value is used on ARM (9223372036854775807 for int64_t). (as @PeterCordes guessed)

EDIT:
For x86 / x64 the overflow will result in an integer with just the MSB set (which equals -9223372036854775808 in case of int64_t).

Comment: The link is for ARMv7, but on ARMv8 / ARM64 it is the same.

Comment: The other pieces of the puzzle you left out of your answer (only mentioned in comments) are that `double d = ...` rounds up because it can't exactly represent that large an integer.  So that's why the conversion overflows at all.  And that on x86, the behaviour is to produce an integer with MSB set, rest clear. (Which Intel calls the "integer indefinite" value: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsd2si)

Comment: @PeterCordes I left all that out because it was mentioned already in the comments (including your comment)  ;-) 
Perhaps I should edit the answers?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, answers should fully answer the question.  Don't assume that future readers will have read any comments (or other answers) before they get to your answer.  A moderator might even come along and move comments to chat.  You can certainly mention comments, e.g. "as mentioned in comments by @Raildex" if that doesn't clutter your answer too much.  (Leaving out attributing is ok if it's something you would have thought of on your own, like something known to most knowledgeable folks in the subject matter, especially if that would bog down your answer.)